# October CMS can't rollback version

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

Since October CMS support forum is read-only, asking my question there.

Can't rollback version from admin panel - the exception is

> "file_put_contents(/var/www/www-root/data/www/foo/plugins/agm/bar/updates/version.yaml): failed to open stream: Permission denied" on line 122 of /var/www/www-root/data/www/foo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php

I have no idea of what kind of permissions needed. 
Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

UPD: After setting a proper permission, new error

> Migration file builder_table_update_agm_foo_events.php already exists. Please use another class name."

popping while trying to rollback.

Comment: may be its needed write permission to that file you can use `chmod` to add permission `sudo chmod -R 777  /var/www/www-root/data/www/foo/plugins/agm/bar/` for that pluing

Comment: After setting a proper permission, new error

Migration file builder_table_update_agm_foo_events.php already exists. Please use another class name."

popping while trying to rollback.

Comment: @Occam'schainsaw Can you mention your version code in question?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand you. A version of what do you mean?

Comment: hmm seems you are in `bad condition` and your profile smily get some wires on it :)  So, .. what i suggest is,  if you have `knowledge how migration works` and you `don't have data yet in DB`, how about `new start`, I suggest in your plugin just remove all files in the `update` folder file except `version.yaml` just edit file and add content like `1.0.1: First version.` to it .. now from database just take your schema for reference and `drop your plugin tables` add those tables back using `builder` i know its `extra work` but hopefully you get proper working version of your plugin.

Comment: Hardik, thank you for your reply!

I fixed it by migrating to initial db settings and executing all migrations again.